# How to attach a Bump Node to a Node setup containing many shaders in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, bump

[Link to my file in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tst2kNfC5vBku4i4WIQ4wzGnxPNooUm-/view?usp=sharing)

File info :File consists of a mesh shaped like a shield that is undergoing a softbody sim. Uses 4 individual materials.

My aim : I need to use Bump on the entire mesh to apply light surface imperfections through a Musgrave texture + Bump node

I saw various tutorials on Youtube involving bump mapping using a noise texture connected to a Bump node connected to a shader's/Principled BSDF's normal input.

Basically, these node setups contain a single shader, so there is a single noise + bump plugged into a shader's normal input.

However, in my file's material I downloaded off the Internet, there are various many shaders, connected to each other through Mix Shaders, etc

How do I use a bump node on the mesh if there are innumerable shaders in my setup, rather than 1? [image: Image of my nnode setup in question, note that this is only one of the 3 materials I have on my mesh]

Comment: Do you have a case against connecting it with displacement into the Displacement Socket of the Material Output?

Comment: @Leander I tried but it didn't work. Person in tutorial plugged into normals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shaders for which a normal input makes sense usually do have a normal input.

You can plug the output of a node into any number of node inputs.

Example :

[image]

Or you can simply use a displacement node and connect it into the displacement input of the "Material Output" node :

[image]

It's hard to get exactly the same result using these two methods. The benefit of the first one is that you can define different bump maps for each type of shader.

Comment: Thank you so so much! If you don't mind me asking, what do you mean by "exact same result"?  By that do you mean the displacement woul look better for my animation over bump?

Comment: I meant that since you are using different nodes with different settings (Displacement vs Bump), it is hard to exactly replicate the look of one using the other. But I don't think there is a "better" method. The first one allows more tweaking because each shader may get its own bump map, and the second one is applied over the whole surface independently from the shaders.

Comment: and both methods will look visually correct when the mesh deforms during softbody right? Also, why doesn't fresnel have any bump plugged into it?

Comment: I don't know much about softbody simulations but I think there shouldn't be a problem if you don't use a too high value of bump. If you see some strange things happening when the mesh gets squashed, you may have to UV unwap your object and use the UV coordinates instead of the generated (used by default)

Comment: wait, why uv coordinates? I'm not using uv textures or uv mapping

Comment: I think the generated coordinates might not take into account that the object was stretched or elongated, depending on how it is handled by the softbody engine. Maybe it won't even be noticeable ? You should try it out and see if you notice something weird

Comment: How do I use uv coordinates instead of generated , and would the way in which my mesh is unwrapped affect the mapping then?

Comment: You should try it out by yourself with what you have now and come ask another question or look for it if you are blocked along the way. :) Don't take my word for the last few comments because I really don't know how softbodies behave with shaders

Comment: sorry I forgot to clarify. How do I use uv coordinates IN PLACE of generated? Is there a setting for that?

Comment: Alright, you just need to add a "Texture Coordinate" node, then plug its UV output into the "Vector" Input of the noise node (or Voronoi or Musgrave...)